# how can I fix the foreach with separate files?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can I fix it the values from fields because when I write in url http://localhost/storeLTE/login/getmodules/1  everything works well, but when I want to pass them through my home with `<?php $this->load->view('modules_view'); ?>`  it isnt work as separate files. how can I fix it?

controller

```
public function getModules($id_module){
        if($this->session->userdata('log')){
            $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
            $menu = array();
            $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
            foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion){
               $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
                $seccions[$index]['data']= $modules;
                if (!count($seccions[$index]['data']))
                    unset($seccions[$index]);
            }
            foreach ($seccions as $item)
                array_push($menu,$item);
          $this->data['fields'] = $menu;
          $this->load->view('modules_view',$this->data);
        }
    }
```

view

```
<div class="row">
            <h3 class="text-center">Welcome to storeLTE, click a module below to get started!</h3>
              <div class="home_module_list">
                  <div class="module_item">
                       <?php $this->load->view('modules_view'); ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

view_modules

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<div class="module_item">
    <?php foreach ($fields as $session) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($session['data'] as $itemData) : ?>
            <div class="module_item" title="<?= $itemData['value'] ?>">
                <a href="<?= $itemData['url'] ?>"><img src="<?= $itemData['icon'] ?>"/></a>
                <a href="<?= $itemData['url'] ?>"><?= $itemData['value']?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following line:

```
<?php $this->load->view('modules_view'); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php $this->load->view('modules_view', ['fields' => $fields]); ?>
```

This should give modules_view.php access to your `$fields` variable from the controller. Hope this helps!